# what is the input of the depth-first search and how does the structure work?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have the following depth-first search code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id: int, importance: int, subordinates: List[int]):
        self.id = id
        self.importance = importance
        self.subordinates = subordinates


class Solution(object):
    def getImportance(self, employees, query_id):
        for e in employees:
            emap = {e.id:e}
        def dfs(eid):             
            employee = emap[eid]
            return (employee.importance + sum(dfs(eid) for eid in employee.subordinates))
        return dfs(query_id)
```

It is the solution to the following bfs Leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance/

And I just need some help understanding what is happening. I understand the initiation of class Employee.

For getImportance function I need some help. So I can see we are mapping the employee id to each employee in a hashmap?

Then in our dfs we define employee to be the mapping of employee to their id?

Finally we return the employee's own importance score together with the sun of all of their subordinates' score.

what does query_id do?

Comment: Is this question about BFS or DFS? They are not the same, and the title/tag is different to the body text.

Comment: Sorry this is DFS

Comment: `In terms of inputs, we will get an 'employee' as an input is that right`...   Not understanding this part

Comment: I have edited the question- I am just unclear about the query_id more than anything in terms of inputs